# C++: compare Eigen::ArrayXd and Eigen::ArrayXXd -- when is automatic casting valid?

Tags: c++, arrays, casting, eigen, eigen3

**Question:** 
When is it valid to assign {to or from} a {row or column} of a two dimensional array (Eigen::ArrayXXd) {to or from} a one-dimensional array (Eigen::ArrayXd)?

**Background:**
I am working with code that uses a 2D array (Eigen::ArrayXXd) to store a set of data. I then have several functions that operate on a single column or row from that data. If I make all of these functions take  Eigen::ArrayXXd as their input and output type, then they can automatically work with either a row or column of the data set. That being said, these functions all operate only on a 1D set of numbers. They do not need to know that the particular set of 1D data is from a 2D array. It would simplify input validation and documentation if I could use 1D arrays for the input and output of the functions.

Answer (score 0):

It looks you can use 1D arrays for assignment to and from columns of rows of a 2D array, at lea for the few simple cases shown below. I'm not sure if there are other situations where this will fail.

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>

Eigen::ArrayXXd fun_2d_d2(Eigen::ArrayXXd data, double scale) { return data * scale; }
Eigen::ArrayXd fun_1d_1d(Eigen::ArrayXd data, double scale) { return data * scale; }
Eigen::ArrayXXd fun_2d_d2_cst(const Eigen::ArrayXXd& data, double val) { return data + val; }
Eigen::ArrayXd fun_1d_1d_cst(const Eigen::ArrayXd& data, double val) { return data + val; }

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  // Create the data:
  int nRow = 5; int nCol = 8;
  Eigen::ArrayXXd data = Eigen::ArrayXXd::Constant(nRow, nCol, 1.0);

  // Call functions with pass by value:
  data.row(1) = fun_2d_d2(data.row(1), 3.0);
  data.row(3) = fun_1d_1d(data.row(3), 4.0);
  data.col(2) = fun_1d_1d(data.col(2), 5.0);

  // Call  functions with pass by constant reference:
  data.row(4) = fun_2d_d2_cst(data.row(4), 3.0);
  data.row(4) = fun_1d_1d_cst(data.row(3), 4.0);
  data.col(5) = fun_1d_1d_cst(data.col(2), 5.0);

  // Print the result:
  std::cout << data << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

This code prints the following output:

```
 1  1  5  1  1 10  1  1
 3  3 15  3  3 20  3  3
 1  1  5  1  1 10  1  1
 4  4 20  4  4 25  4  4
 8  8 24  8  8 29  8  8
```